# amazon apiで取得できる情報について

Tags: php, api, amazon

amazon apiに関する質問です。
調べてもよくわからなかったので質問させて頂きます。
apiを使用して商品の下記の情報を取得することは可能でしょうか？
・商品名
・メーカー
・値段
・商品説明文
・商品画像
詳しい方、ご教示ください。宜しくお願い致します。

Comment: 「Product Advertising API php」で検索すると説明やらサンプルコードやら出てきますよ。

Answer (score 1):

公式のドキュメントをみると、「ItemLookup」で商品名、メーカーは取得できますね。
「CartAdd」で一回カートに入れれば、値段も取得できそうです。
ただ、さくっと見た感じだと商品説明文と商品画像は取得できなさそうなので、いっそ「ItemLookup」で取得できるDetailPageURLからスクレイピングして直接全部取ってくるのが良いんじゃないでしょうか。

[Product Advertising API](https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/09/associates/paapi/dg/index.html?rw_useCurrentProtocol=1)

Answer (score 1):

ItemLookupでResponseGroupにItemAttributes,Offers,Reviewsを設定したら帰ってくると思いますよ。
多くイメージが欲しい場合はImagesも追加します。

プログラムを作って試してみるのも手ですが
アカウントを持っているなら以下のページの左側にあるLookup-itemLookupを選択し、必要情報(Marketplace,associate Tagなど)を記載後に実際のデータを見ることができます。
http://webservices.amazon.co.jp/scratchpad/index.html